# Mirror dual monitors with mirrored panel including system tray

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, desktop-environments

Is there a desktop environment that allows full mirroring in a dual monitor setup, such that the panel, including the indicators/system tray icons, are also mirrored?
In other words, similar to "Duplicate these displays" in Windows.

Comment: In your Settings then in Displays choose Mirror displays

Comment: Which desktop environment? It doesn't mirror the panel in Xfce, and from what I have read, not in Gnome either. In KDE, it doesn't even detect my second monitor.

Comment: I use Xfce4 all the time and it mirrors exactly screen to screen.  Panels and all.

Comment: Also system icons? Do you use Xubuntu? I am asking because I did not succeed in this with MX Linux 19 Xfce, or with Kubuntu 19.10.

Comment: I use Xubuntu 18.04 LTS.  It uses the Xfce4 DE.  Clones everything from icons, panels, wallpapers, etc.  It is exact duplication from one monitor to the other.

Comment: Thanks. So you could post it as an answer, then.