# Enforce copied settings of two panes across separate screens in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, customization, plasma

I've got a two monitor setup, and I've spent an hour customising it, I now only have one problem - I want to use the same dock / application menu bar on both my screens, If I make a change to one, the other remains unaffected. Is there a workaround for KDE Plasma?

Thanks.

Comment: I've posted a link to this question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/f99sn2/can_a_panel_on_one_monitor_be_cloned_onto_a/).

Comment: Sadly, the only response there so far implies using latte-dock as a possible solution. I don't have two monitors and so can't check it out. However, if you're open to using another desktop environment altogether, see the comments [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1212714/248158).

Comment: I am actually using Latte Dock, it's brilliant, except it also suffers the same issue. Another reason I chose KDE was because of how customisable it is and how familiar I am with it. Ideally, I would stick with it

Comment: You can post a new thread over at reddit describing what you want specifically mentioning latte dock and its version. The developer is pretty active there.

Comment: Please read http://psifidotos.blogspot.com/2019/05/latte-and-shared-layouts-dream.html. Maybe there's some help there.